# ASP.NET Membership change password not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have this code for changing a user's password when they click the password reset button (with extra code to log to ELMAH so I can try to figure out what is going wrong).

This is in ASP.NET MVC 2, using the standard aspnet membership provider, with a simple View like this:

```
New Password:     ______
Confirm Password: ______
[Reset] [Cancel]
```

The route to this view is `/Account/Reset/guid`, where guid is the user's id in the aspnet membership database.

The key portion of the code is where it calls `user.ChangePassword()`.  You can see that it logs a message when successful.  The problem is that for some users, the success message is logged, but they can not log in with the new password.  For other users it logs the success message and they can log in.

```
if (user.ChangePassword(pwd, confirmPassword))
{
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
        new Exception("ResetPassword - changed successfully!"));
    return Json(new { 
        Msg = "You have reset your password successfully." }, 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

The full code listing is:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ResetPassword(string id, string newPassword, string confirmPassword)
{
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("ResetPassword started for " + id));

    ViewData["PasswordLength"] = Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPassword))
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
            new Exception("ResetPassword - new password was blank."));
        ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "Please enter a new password.");
        return Json(new { Errors = ModelState.Errors() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    if (newPassword.Length < Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength)
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
            new Exception("ResetPassword - new password was less than minimum length."));
        ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", 
            string.Format("The password must be at least {0} characters long.", 
            Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength));
        return Json(new { Errors = ModelState.Errors() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(confirmPassword))
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
            new Exception("ResetPassword - confirm password was blank."));
        ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", 
            "Please enter the same new password in the confirm password textbox.");
        return Json(new { Errors = ModelState.Errors() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    if (confirmPassword.Length < Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength)
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
            new Exception("ResetPassword - confirm password was less than minimum length."));
        ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", 
            string.Format("The password must be at least {0} characters long.", 
            Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength));
        return Json(new { Errors = ModelState.Errors() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    if (confirmPassword != newPassword)
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
            new Exception("ResetPassword - new password did not match the confirm password."));
        ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "Please enter the same password again.");
        return Json(new { Errors = ModelState.Errors() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    bool isMatch = ValidationHelper.IsGUID(id);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) || !isMatch)
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
            new Exception("ResetPassword - id was not a guid."));
        ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "An invalid ID value was passed in through the URL");
    }
    else
    {
        //ID exists and is kosher, see if this user is already approved
        //Get the ID sent in the querystring
        Guid userId = new Guid(id);

        try
        {
            //Get information about the user
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                //could not find the user
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
                    new Exception("ResetPassword - could not find user by id " + id));
                ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", 
                    "The user account can not be found in the system.");
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
                    new Exception("ResetPassword - user is " + user.UserName));
                string pwd = user.ResetPassword();

                if (user.ChangePassword(pwd, confirmPassword))
                {
                    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
                        new Exception("ResetPassword - changed successfully!"));
                    return Json(new { 
                        Msg = "You have reset your password successfully." }, 
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
                    new Exception("ResetPassword 
                    - failed to change the password, for an unknown reason"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
                new Exception("ResetPassword: " + ex));
            return Json(new { Error = ex.Message + " -> " 
                + ex.InnerException.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    return Json(new { Errors = ModelState.Errors() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Edit: Adding a bounty to try to get this solved.  This is one of the most annoying problems on my issue list, and I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Have you actually witnessed this yourself?  Are you 100% sure the user isn't just mistyping their password?  Are there trailing / leading spaces in the password on this page that might be getting stripped out of the login page?

Comment: Also, what is the specific error message the user is getting when they attempt to log in?  Is something else resetting their password in the meantime?  Basically, the MembershipProvider works as far as anyone knows, and the code you've posted looks good, so my guess is either the problem isn't a problem, or it's in other code.

Comment: I've tried it myself by resetting the password to "password1" and then trying to log in immediately.  I could not log in (username or password incorrect).  For other users and for my own account I can change the password.

Comment: Is this the standard SQL Server ASP.NET membership or another?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to send a username to the ResetPassword function? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.resetpassword.aspx

Comment: Looks like @adrift got the answer - user.IsApproved was false.  Although I think that only explains the new user that I was using as an example.  Other users have been using the site for a while before having the password problem (so they were approved)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the user needs to reset his password, there is a chance their account has been locked out from too many invalid attempts.  If this is the case, then the password is being reset successfully, but the user cannot log in until the lockout condition is cleared.

Try checking [MembershipUser.IsLockedOut](http://MembershipUser.IsLockedOut):

> Users are most commonly locked out and
>   cannot be validated by the
>   ValidateUser method when the
>   MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts is reached
>   within the PasswordAttemptWindow.
>
> To set this property to false and let
>   the user try to log in again, you can
>   use the UnlockUser method.

*Edit*

Did you also check [IsApproved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isapproved.aspx)?  Authentication will fail is this is `false` for the user.

Also, assuming by default membership provider, you mean the SqlMembershipProvider, can you run the following query against your database and make sure everything looks correct?

```
select IsApproved, IsLockedOut, FailedPasswordAttemptCount
from aspnet_Membership
where ApplicationId = @yourApplicationId and UserId = @userId
```

Try executing the query before attempting to sign in to verify `IsApproved` and `IsLockedOut` are ok.  Also note the value for `FailedPasswordAttemptCount`.

Try signing in, and then run the query again.  If signin fails, has the value for `FailedPasswordAttemptCount` been incremented?

You could also look at `PasswordFormat` in the aspnet_Membership table and make sure it is the correct value depending on the format you are using (0 for Clear, 1 for Hashed, and 2 for Encrypted).

Comment: yeah sorry I forgot to mention it - I have checked the IsLockedOut property and the user is not locked out.

Comment: @JK, please see my edits above.  Hopefully one of these suggestions will help you turn up a clue that helps.  I'm curious about what the problem turns out to be.

Comment: +1 IsApproved was false - looks like the problem has been found :)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I've always used

```
bool MembershipUser.ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword)
```

I've never had an issue with it returning true and the password not being changed correctly.
As fas as I can tell your code looks ok. It is difficult to follow, with all the Elmah noise in there. (you might want to remove it or replace with a simple log call so it's easier to follow).

Verify that the string id that you pass as an argument corresponds to the UserId of the intended user. You might be sending the userId from some other user and changing that users password instead.

Comment: The logging includes a message that displays `user.UserName` - and it is showing the correct name every time.  I will try using `MembershipUser.ChangePassword` instead of `user.ChangePassword()`.

Comment: You are using it correctly. It's not a static method. I just wrote the signature so it's clear which method I was refering to. ;-)

Comment: BTW, you don't need JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet since your ResetPassword action is handling only Post requests. [HttpPost] Attribute.

Comment: @santiago OK I wont change it then.  I'm lost, I cant see why user.ChangePassword returns true, but then you cant login with that new password.  I tried it myself using the guid of a user who could not change her password, and confirmed this does happen.

Comment: Strange case. While you are still tracking the issue be sure to log the confirmPassword argument as well. You never know, it might not be what you are expecting. It could for example be url encoded if they used some special characters (<,>, etc..)

Comment: @santiago I tried to change it to "password1" and it did not work.

Comment: @JK, did u ever get this figured out?

Comment: @santiago no its still a problem, so I've just added a big bounty to solve it

Comment: did you add the code to log the new password?
You are 100% sure that thew password being used in MembershipUser.ChangePassword is the correct one?

Comment: @JK, after you change the password successfully make sure that
 bool shouldAlwaysBeTrue = user.ValidateUser(username, string password);
returns true.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited - following answer is false see comments**

So wait are you trying to locate someone by a Guid?  By doing

```
Guid userId = new Guid(id);
```

You are practically creating a guaranteed to be unique ID.  So my guess is you are never finding a user and you are resetting a password successfully for nobody.  Can you not just find them by the id parameter you pass in?

Comment: No, calling new Guid(some string) just converts that string into a Guid.  It is correctly locating the user.

Comment: Guid userId = new Guid(id) converts the string id parameter to a Guid. It does not generate a completely new Guid. Since Membership.GetUser expects a Guid, you have to use this conversion.

Comment: right sorry not thinking straight here tonight edited the post so no one takes it to be true.  not sure otherwise then the code looks fine to me and of course its not really raising any exceptions so I would guess its an error on the database side.  so you aren't having problems with any other password methods?

Comment: @JK looking at your comment to santiago - do you happen to have sample passwords you confirmed work and sample ones you dont?  or are you running into the situation that a given password will work on some submits but not on others?

Comment: Yes, I can change some users passwords to "password1" and other users I can not change to the same "password1"

Comment: very strange.  is the default membership provider the same for all of the users?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<%@ Page Title="Change Password" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="ChangePassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebPages.Account.ChangePassword" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Change Password
    </h2>
    <p>
        Use the form below to change your password.
    </p>
    <p>
        New passwords are required to be a minimum of <%= Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength %> characters in length.
    </p>
    <asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangeUserPassword" runat="server" CancelDestinationPageUrl="~/" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false" 
        OnChangedPassword="ChangeUserPassword_ChangedPassword">
        <ChangePasswordTemplate>
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ChangeUserPasswordValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                 ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup"/>
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <fieldset class="changePassword">
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="CurrentPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CurrentPassword">Old Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CurrentPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CurrentPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Old Password is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="NewPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="NewPassword">New Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="NewPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NewPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="New Password is required." ToolTip="New Password is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="ConfirmNewPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmNewPassword">Confirm New Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmNewPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmNewPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Confirm New Password is required."
                             ToolTip="Confirm New Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="NewPasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="NewPassword" ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Confirm New Password must match the New Password entry."
                             ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
                <p class="submitButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelPushButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="ChangePasswordPushButton" runat="server" CommandName="ChangePassword" Text="Change Password" 
                         ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </ChangePasswordTemplate>
        <SuccessTemplate>
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <fieldset class="changePassword">
                    <legend>Password changed</legend>
                        <p>
                            Your password has been changed. A confirmation e-mail has been sent to you.
                        </p>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </SuccessTemplate>
    </asp:ChangePassword>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the problem is that you are resetting the password right before you change it.  Without getting into all of the internals of the Membership class, could you try putting in some kind of delay between those two commands?

Answer (score 1):

Which MemberShipProvider are you using? Is it the same for every user? For instance, if you use SqlMembershipProvider and set enablePasswordReset to false, it will quietly fail to update the password. ChangePassword, in this case, returns true as if everything went fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the built-in SQLServer based providers take a look at your SQL Stored procs.  This is what my default proc looks like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.aspnet_Membership_SetPassword
    @ApplicationName  nvarchar(256),
    @UserName         nvarchar(256),
    @NewPassword      nvarchar(128),
    @PasswordSalt     nvarchar(128),
    @CurrentTimeUtc   datetime,
    @PasswordFormat   int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserId uniqueidentifier
    SELECT  @UserId = NULL
    SELECT  @UserId = u.UserId
    FROM    dbo.aspnet_Users u, dbo.aspnet_Applications a, dbo.aspnet_Membership m
    WHERE   LoweredUserName = LOWER(@UserName) AND
            u.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId  AND
            LOWER(@ApplicationName) = a.LoweredApplicationName AND
            u.UserId = m.UserId

    IF (@UserId IS NULL)
        RETURN(1)

    UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Membership
    SET Password = @NewPassword, PasswordFormat = @PasswordFormat, PasswordSalt = @PasswordSalt,
        LastPasswordChangedDate = @CurrentTimeUtc
    WHERE @UserId = UserId
    RETURN(0)
END
```

As you can see the update statement could totally fail and the stored proc could return true.  I think this is where your errors are probably coming from.  Could be locking issues...

Answer (score 1):

Well this is certainly an interesting one. The "it works for some, not for others" part is really bizarre.

Is this an intermittent problem, or does it **always** occur for certain users, and **always not occur** for other users?

One of the other people here suggested running `ValidateUser(username, newPassword)` to confirm that the user could properly authenticate before assuming success.

Have you tried this? You could continuously loop, resetting + changing the password until ValidateUser is successful, perhaps exiting after N failures.

```
bool success = false;
int numAttempts = 0;
do
{
    string pwd = user.ResetPassword();
    if (user.ChangePassword(pwd, confirmPassword))
    {
        success = Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserName, pwd);
    }
    numAttempts++;
} while(numAttempts < 5 && !success);
```

**Note:** This is not for use in production, just for testing to see if this resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 1 webserver or multiple webservers? With multiple servers it could be that the machinekey used for encrypting the password is not the same on al servers.

Answer (score 0):

Could your main catch block be throwing an exception itself that you haven't noticed?

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("ResetPassword: " + ex));
    return Json(new { Error = ex.Message + " -> " 
            + ex.InnerException.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The ex.InnerException.Message statement is not safe because it could throw a NullReferenceException.