# ChangePassword Control doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-membershipprovider

Im currently doing an application in .net using c# and I want to use the change password control.

The problem is...I always get an error of "Password incorrect or New Password invalid. New Password length minimum: 1. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 0."

Even if I supplied the correct parameters of the password and set the (minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0") in Mebership provider in my web.config.

```
<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword1" runat="server" BackColor="#EFF3FB" BorderColor="#B5C7DE"
    BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana"
    Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333" 
    ChangePasswordButtonText="Change" 
    ChangePasswordTitleText="Password change"
    ConfirmNewPasswordLabelText="Retype new password:" 
    NewPasswordLabelText="New Password:">
</asp:ChangePassword>
```

i'm implementing my own MembershipProvider:

```
public class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider 
{
    ...

    public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider"
      type="My.Security.BsAsMembershipProvider"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      applicationName="MyApp"
      requiresUniqueEmail="true"
      passwordFormat="Clear"
      passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
      description="My custom membership provider"
    />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: let's see your Membership configuration in the web.config

Comment: Could this link help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048460/asp-net-membership-change-password-not-working

Comment: nop, thanks, i read all the post, but I'm in the same situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, I had not implemented MyMemberShipUser ChangePassword method.

```
public class MyMembershipUser : MembershipUser
{
    public MyMembershipUser()
    {
    }

    public MyMembershipUser(string username)
        : base("MyMembershipProvider", username, null, "", "", "", true, true, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today)
    {
    }

    public override bool ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword)        
    {

        //Do something

    }
}
```